WCF timeout so quickly
I'm experiencing a timeout issue with WCF communication between two solutions. Occasionally, we receive the following error:

The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after
00:00:00.0669402. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to
Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time
allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer
timeout.

As you can see, the timeout occurs very quickly—after approximately 67 milliseconds. However, our binding configurations specify timeouts of 1 minute and 30 seconds. Here are the binding configurations from our
App.config:
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CommonHttpBinding" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:01:30" sendTimeout="00:01:30">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="CommonHttpsBinding" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:01:30" sendTimeout="00:01:30">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="MtomHttpBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="MtomHttpsBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding_GlobalAuthenticate">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="GiantAnonymousTimeoutLongHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="24:00:00" sendTimeout="24:00:00">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="GiantAnonymousTimeoutLongHttpsBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="24:00:00" sendTimeout="24:00:00">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

This is the endpoint configuration between the solutions:
<client>
    <endpoint contract="ServiceContract" address="adress" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CommonHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="Client"/>
</client>

And here are my client-side configurations:
<system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
    <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
  </connectionManagement>
</system.net>

Question:
Why does the timeout error occur so quickly, despite the sendTimeout and receiveTimeout being set to 1 minute and 30 seconds? Are there other settings that could be causing this rapid timeout?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Check other things like : Are you exceeding the max buffer aka any  limits ? are you running this in a threading manner or async that would pre-emptively end ?

Hello @Franck, I have added my binding configuration. The method is not running in a threading manner or asynchronously and will not pre-emptively end. It is a straightforward, synchronous call.

Are you opening a new service client every single time or use only 1 for the whole lifetime of the application ? Also noticed you specify https bindings, are you actually using https and if yes do you have by any chance a proxy in between you and the server

I am using a scoped lifetime for the service client. While I have HTTPS binding settings configured, for this endpoint I am actually using HTTP binding settings.

First you need to make sure that your client and service are running on the same thread.
Depending on the error message, you need to increase the sendtimeout or receivetimemout time. In addition, there are two other timeouts in wcf binding: opentimeout and closetimeout. You can add them like this:
<bindings>
 <basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="InTimeout" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" >
  </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

You can also refer to this link : WCF Timeout.
Hope it helps you.

Hello, thank you for the answer. The server and client run on different solutions, not the same thread.

Could the Server run properly? Or is there any error logs?

Add SendTimeout, OpenTimeout, CloseTimout in client and server config and see if it helps. Please check this Microsoft Learn page for the explanation of these timeout values.
